# The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist. in visual studio 2015 xamarin cross platform on windows 8.1

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I created a project and built it. It started showing error on MainActivity.cs on Resource.Layout.tabbar and toolbar. [tabbar and tool bar error on MainActivity.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7ICw.png)

Then I changed the .FormsAppCompatActivity to .FormsApplicationActivity and then commented the tabbar and toolbar line of code and build.

tabbar and toolbar comment on MainActivity.cs

[image: tabbar and toolbar comment on MainActivity.cs]

Then I build, that was when I saw this error:

> The file “obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources” does not exist. in visual studio 2015 xamarin cross platform on windows 8.1

The main project will build but the Andriod section won't build.

[Main project build successfully][3]

Fail to build App.Andriod

[image: Fail to build App.Andriod]

Please, I really need help because it's over a month and I have not solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

These errors can occur due to a number of reasons.

1. You have a resource in your Resources folder with a dash in it. e.g. '-'. These aren't valid and you should replace them with an underscore.
2. You aren't using the correct build tools. Open up the Android SDK Manager, and ensure you have the latest Platform Build Tools. Or at least the build tools that match the SDK you are compiling for.

If these points don't help, you will need to look at the detailed output during build to give you more of a hint. In Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options, then the Xamarin section.

Click on Android Settings, then set Output verbosity to Diagnostics.

When you try to build next, in the Output window, it will display a massive amount of detail, and the error that is occurring will be in there. It might take a little bit of sifting through to find out what is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks Adam Pedley. i really appreciate. but am having a little problem on renaming the folder in the resource folder.

Comment: Inside your Resources folder, you will have other folders such as drawable. Inside these folders, just check if there are any dashes, in any of the file names. You can leave the folder names as is. There is an exception to the dash. The reason they don't allow them, is because it is used to give the OS more information. e.g. -hdpi, tells Android to only use these resources when on a device in hdpi. You can leave these folder names as is.

Comment: So it wont be a problem ab

Comment: Thanks Adam for your answer. I work with Xamarin, and my problem was a resource file with an space in its name.